# How can I check whether a integer data in dataframe column has same number of digits?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to check if the column data has same number of digit.

I have following dataset

```
District    Prefix  Quota       
A           98426   783
A           98427   223
A           98446   127
A           98626   51
B           98049   167
B           98079   153
B           98140   120
B           98159   139
B           98169   182
B           98249   86
B           98426   588
B           98446   96
C           98049   104
C           98060   68
C           98149   65
C           98150   68
C           98159   86
C           98160   80
C           98169   113
```

Code to reproduce:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['A', 98426, 783],
    ['A', 98427, 223],
    ['A', 98446, 127],
    ['A', 98626, 51],
    ['B', 98049, 167],
    ['B', 98079, 153],
    ['B', 98140, 120],
    ['B', 98159, 139],
    ['B', 98169, 182],
    ['B', 98249, 86],
    ['B', 98426, 588],
    ['B', 98446, 96],
    ['C', 98049, 104],
    ['C', 98060, 68],
    ['C', 98149, 65],
    ['C', 98150, 68],
    ['C', 98159, 86],
    ['C', 98160, 80],
    ['C', 98169, 113]
], 
    columns=['District', 'Prefix', 'Quota'])
```

as you can see in "prefix" column, all the numbers is of 5 digits. but lets suppose there is inconsistency in digits like the first data is of 6 digits or 4 digits. how can I make sure all the digit in integer is same?

I tried `len(str(round(df.Prefix.mean())))` that will give the number of digits but it calculates mean first and gives the number of digits of that mean. but I cant check the consistency

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one approach using `str.len` and `nunique`.

**Ex:**

```
print(df['Prefix'].astype(str).str.len().nunique() == 1) #--> True
```

Comment: it just checks whether all the numbers is 5 or not. .lets suppose a column has 100 data and all the data has 3 digit number, which means there is consistency. but the above code will indicate "False" output. it not necessary that the numbers should be of 5 digits. but should be consistance

Comment: May i know how you decided that 3 is the length, Example in the 100 rows you have 50 rows with length of 2 and the other 50 with length of 5...How do you decide between 2 & 5?

Comment: there is nothing to decide between them as there is inconsistency in digits, therefore output should be "False". if all the rows were of same digit than the output should be "True"

Comment: Ok i understand use `df['Prefix'].astype(str).str.len().nunique() == 1`